# Unlink function script is not working in php

Tags: php

I Want to use this code update image working fine but. I have need add unlink function this code so please help me ... where add code **unlink function**. I am using PHP 7.2 and database

> Note: the Previous File Delete in a file after update new file
>
> show error=>Warning: unlink(image/Banner-70399.jpg): No such file or
>   directory in D:\xammp\htdocs\trustandmeet\admin\update-imagebanner.php
>   on line 43
>
> line number 43 is here =>unlink("image/$image");

```php
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM banner WHERE banner_id='$banner_id'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
    mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0;
    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
    $fileinfo = @getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    $width = $fileinfo[0];
    $height = $fileinfo[1];
    if (!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
        $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $image = "Banner" . '-' . rand(10000, 99999) . '.' . $extension;
    }
    if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 2000000) {
        $response = array(
            "type" => "error",
            ($_SESSION['msg1'] = "Image size exceeds 2MB"),
        );
    } elseif ($width < "900" || $height < "250") {
        $response = array(
            "type" => "error",
            ($_SESSION['msg2'] = "the image should be used greater than 900 X 250 "),
        );
    } else {
        $location = "image/banner/" . $image;
        unlink("image/$image");
        if (in_array(strtolower($extension), ['png', 'jpeg', 'jpg'])) {
            compressImage($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $location, 60);
        } else {
            $image = $row1['image'];
        }

        $sql = mysqli_query(
            $conn,
            "update  banner set Image='$image' where banner_id='$banner_id' "
        );

        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Successfully Banner Image Updated Successfully !!";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Do you know what the `unlink` function does?  Where do you try to use it?  In what way does the code fail?  If you're asking where to use the `unlink` function, well, you'd use it where you want to delete the file.

Comment: sir, I have need script update image before old image delete after a new image update

Comment: We can appreciate that English is not your native language, but I'm afraid you're going to have to take some time and clarify the problem so we can understand and help.

Comment: unlink("../image/banner/".$image"); code apply its posible but where ?

Comment: I want to delete the old image in file location after update new image

Comment: And have you tried to do this?  You appear to already have in mind the exact line of code you want to use, so what's stopping you from using it?  What happens when you *try*?  Does it fail in some specific way?  Currently the problem is not that your code doesn't work, the problem is that you're reluctant to try.  You are encouraged to make the edits you want to make to your code and test it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to remove an image that ia in the `banner` directory but your `unlink` command does not include that directory. Instead of:

```
$location = "image/banner/".$image;
unlink("image/$image");
```

Use:

```
unlink($location);
```

Comment: Warning :  unlink(image/banner/Banner-64084.jpgBanner-64084.jpg): No such file or directory in D:\xammp\htdocs\trustandmeet\admin\update-imagebanner.php on line 43

Comment: if use  this  unlink("image/$image");  => Warning : unlink(image/Banner-72477.jpg): No such file or directory in  D:\xammp\htdocs\trustandmeet\admin\update-imagebanner.php on line 43

Comment: I modified the answer. You already had the image name included in the `$location` variable so the `unlink` didn't need another copy.